# Why Does this Bootstrap Template have a left to right scrollbar?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm currently studying Bootstrap 4 and was creating a Bootstrap 4 template for my personal study. However, the following code creates a left to right scrollbar on the website when you look at in the browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Practice</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="wdith-device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
        <style>
            .Box{padding: 60px 10px; background: #ddd}
            .Box:nth-child(even){background: #eee;}
            h1, h2{margin: 30px 0;}
            .container-fluid, .container{max-width:1400px;}
            .carousel-indicators li {width: 10px; height: 10px; border-radius: 100%;}
/*          .navbar-brand{position: relative;}
            .custom-nav{position: absolute;}*/
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- MODAL POPUP -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="modalExample">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h2 class="modal-title"> Modal Title </h2>
                        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>"Begin today!" That's all the note said. There was no indication from where it came or who may have written it. Had it been meant for someone else? Meghan looked around the room, but nobody made eye contact back. For a brief moment, she thought it might be a message for her to follow her dreams, but ultimately decided it was easier to ignore it as she crumpled it up and threw it away.</p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- end .modal-content -->
            </div> <!-- end .modal-dialog -->
        </div> <!-- end .modal -->
        <!-- MODAL END-->

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light row">
            <a class="navbar-brand col-1 border border-primary" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse col-11 custom-nav border border-primary" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown Tab</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Tab 2</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel slide" id="ExampleSlide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="1000">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#ExampleSlide" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#ExampleSlide" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#ExampleSlide" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img class="w-100" src="1.png">
                        <div class="carousel-caption"><h5>Image 1</h5></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="w-100" src="2.png">
                        <div class="carousel-caption"><h5>Image 2</h5></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="w-100" src="3.png">
                        <div class="carousel-caption"><h5>Image 3</h5></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev"href="#ExampleSlide" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next"href="#ExampleSlide" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid row">
            <div class="offset-1 col-10">
                <h1 class="display-1">Heading 1</h1>
                <p class="h1">"Begin today!" That's all the note said. There was no indication from where it came or who may have written it. Had it been meant for someone else? Meghan looked around the room, but nobody made eye contact back. For a brief moment, she thought it might be a message for her to follow her dreams, but ultimately decided it was easier to ignore it as she crumpled it up and threw it away.</p>
                <p class="lead">Stranded. Yes, she was now the first person ever to land on Venus, but that was of little consequence. Her name would be read by millions in school as the first to land here, but that celebrity would never actually be seen by her. She looked at the control panel and knew there was nothing that would ever get it back into working order. She was the first and it was not clear this would also be her last.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='container'>

            <!-- ACCORDION -->
            <div class="card-group" id="exampleAccordion">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-white bg-primary">
                        <h3 class="card-title" data-target="#card-1" data-toggle="collapse">Accordion Example 1</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse" id="card-1">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p>"Begin today!" That's all the note said. There was no indication from where it came or who may have written it. Had it been meant for someone else? Meghan looked around the room, but nobody made eye contact back. For a brief moment, she thought it might be a message for her to follow her dreams, but ultimately decided it was easier to ignore it as she crumpled it up and threw it away.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- ACCORDION END -->
            <!-- Accordion은 기본적으로 열리고 닫히는 dropdown과 비슷한 기능을 가진 element라고 보면 된다. -->
            <!-- Accordion은 collapse를 사용하여 만든다. -->

            <div class="card-deck">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-white bg-primary">
                        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p>"Begin today!" That's all the note said. There was no indication from where it came or who may have written it. Had it been meant for someone else? Meghan looked around the room, but nobody made eye contact back. For a brief moment, she thought it might be a message for her to follow her dreams, but ultimately decided it was easier to ignore it as she crumpled it up and threw it away.</p>
                        <p>Stranded. Yes, she was now the first person ever to land on Venus, but that was of little consequence. Her name would be read by millions in school as the first to land here, but that celebrity would never actually be seen by her. She looked at the control panel and knew there was nothing that would ever get it back into working order. She was the first and it was not clear this would also be her last.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <p><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="This is the info you are looking for... #1">More Info</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-white bg-danger">
                        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p>"Begin today!" That's all the note said. There was no indication from where it came or who may have written it. Had it been meant for someone else? Meghan looked around the room, but nobody made eye contact back. For a brief moment, she thought it might be a message for her to follow her dreams, but ultimately decided it was easier to ignore it as she crumpled it up and threw it away.</p>
                        <p>Stranded. Yes, she was now the first person ever to land on Venus, but that was of little consequence. Her name would be read by millions in school as the first to land here, but that celebrity would never actually be seen by her. She looked at the control panel and knew there was nothing that would ever get it back into working order. She was the first and it was not clear this would also be her last.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <p><span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalExample"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="The Title">More Info</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $(".nav li a").on("click", function(){
                $(".nav li a").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
            });

            $(function () {
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
            });

            $('.carousel').carousel({
                pause: false,
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can't find the reason why this might be... Does anybody know why this is happening? I want the web page to be just 100% on the screen, not having to scroll from left to right.

https://jsfiddle.net/8wvszpqa/

*edit: The scrollbar I'm meaning is one the picture below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your issue but tryin to help. Remove those codes from your script to get rid of the bar.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="carousel slide" id="ExampleSlide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="1000">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#ExampleSlide" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#ExampleSlide" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#ExampleSlide" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="w-100" src="1.png">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h5>Image 1</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="w-100" src="2.png">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h5>Image 2</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="w-100" src="3.png">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h5>Image 3</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#ExampleSlide" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#ExampleSlide" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: sorry , ı was about the top of the page. ı think it s about your codes are not fit the page horizantally. there is a general problem about the css attributes width padding etc.

Comment: but in that situation , you can solve your problem by those; 

'body {
            overflow-x: hidden;
}'